# Angular 6: xyz.service.ts running client or server side? Exposing API-URLs/DB-Passwords?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, security, angular6

I'm currently tooling around, trying some stuff and at the moment I'm working with Angular.

I stumbled over this [Tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course) and I followed the steps and got the basic example Application working

Now in the `data.service.ts` I defined the method getUsers()

```
getUsers() {
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
}
```

In the Tutorial the jsonplaceholder-api is used.
My question is, If I would build an application with Angular and publish it, can the User see the API-URL or is the Typescript/Javascript running on Node.js on Server side and the client only sees a request 'getUsers()' and the responding JSON without the actual API-URL?

In a second thought, if I want to use my own Database for Users do I have to build an API for my let's say MySQL-DB, or can I connect directly to the DB like with this JavaScript-Snippet:

```
var mysql = require('mysql')

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'my_schema',
});
```

Let's say if its possible to connect directly to a database like this - will there be a security issue because the connection to the DB will be built on the client side and maybe exposing the password?

Comment: user will see any http request (url, body, header...) performed by the browser. Don't do any access to your database from the client it's a security risk.

Comment: All Javascript running in the browser is viewable in the browser.  All AJAX requests are also viewable in the browser.  If, however, you do have a server-side application (Node.js, as suggested but not tagged) then the clients will never have access to that.

Comment: @KilledByCheese It would be helpful if you could accept the answer or elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say if its possible to connect directly to a database like this
>   - will there be a security issue because the connection to the DB will be built on the client side and maybe exposing the password?

**Yes**, there is a security issue; however, it may fit your use case if it is client-managed software.

> In a second thought, if I want to use my own Database for Users do I
>   have to build an API for my let's say MySQL-DB, or can I connect
>   directly to the DB like with this JavaScript-Snippet:

I would recommend building an API (e.g. RESTful) and integrate client/user authentication that is verified on the server before accessing any useful information with all the bells and whistles that entails. (`encryption-in-transit`, `hashing`, `endpoint` security etc).

This depends on what your software is being used for. If it is just a mini-project to test `Angular` things, then feel free to focus on learning the front-end development.

Good luck!

<sub>Any local JavaScript code can be hacked, analyse the risk of exposing any public API keys embedded in your code. You could encrypt your local database files, but if the encryption is implemented by the client only, that is not safe either.</sub>

[Chrome DevTools Network tab on this Stack Overflow page. You might be familiar with this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tgBW.png) Although I didn't notice any JSON objects in the response bodies, you get the gist. The same `http` components that you use to access the APIs in your code can be accessed here quite clearly.

<sub>I'm pretty sure there are no dangerous API keys being revealed in this example.<sub>Don't quote me on that<sub>Help me</sub></sub></sub> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>